# java overriding,ambiguous with example

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous

i'm having hard time understanding how the compiler chooses between the functions, lets say we have this example:

Class A:

```
public class A {
    public void foo(A a,B b){
        System.out.println("#1");
        goo(a,b);
    }

    public void goo(A a1,A a2){
        System.out.println("#2");
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A {
    public void foo(C c,A a){
        System.out.println("#3");
        goo(a,c);
    }

    public void goo(C c,B b){
        System.out.println("#4");
}
```

Class C:

```
 public class C extends B {
    public void foo(C c,B b){
        System.out.println("#5");
        goo(c,b);
    }
    public void goo(A a,B b){
        System.out.println("#6");
        goo(b,a);
     }
     public void goo(B b,C c){
        System.out.println("#7");
        goo(c,b);
     }
```

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        A a=new C();
        B b= new C();
        C c = new C();
        c.foo(c, c);//output #5 #4
        b.foo(c, c);//compilation error 
        b.goo(null, null);//output #4
        c.goo(a,c);//output #6 #2
```

why we receive a compilation error in  "b.foo(c, c);"   and in "c.foo(c, c);" we print #5 #4 ?

and whats the difference between both calls ?

and in "b.goo(null, null);//output #4" why the output isn't #2 ?

c.goo(a,c);//output #6 #2
why we print #6 and not #7,
and afterwards we print #2.

Comment: check [JLS 15.12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1) and [JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts here overriding and overload.

**Overriding**

> The benefit of overriding is: ability to define a behavior that's
>   specific to the subclass type, which means a subclass can implement a
>   parent class method based on its requirement. In object-oriented
>   terms, overriding means to override the functionality of an existing
>   method.

In simpler words: if one child class has a method with SAME SIGNATURE of its parent it is telling to JVM "when call this method, forget about my parents method use mine!"

**Overload**

> Overloading allows different methods to have same name, but different
>   signatures where signature can differ by number of input parameters or
>   type of input parameters or both. Overloading is related to compile
>   time (or static) polymorphism.

In simpler words, methods with same name but different number or types of parameters are different methods, it doesn't matter if you are extending the class or not.

When you call an overloaded method, at compilet time JVM tries to fit your call in every definition of that method possible, if your call doesn't fit any possible definition you have compilation problem METHOD NOT FOUND, if it fits in more than one definition the AMBIGUOS DEFINITION

Trying to study your case:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        A a=new C();
        B b= new C();
        C c = new C();
        c.foo(c, c);//output #5 #4
        b.foo(c, c);//compilation error 
        b.goo(null, null);//output #4
        c.goo(a,c);//output #6 #2
}
```

You instantiate all your objects as `C`, but for the JVM it doesn't matter what is on the right side of `=`, your calls will be dealing with the method of the types on left side of the assertion

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below example for better understanding:

```
    abstract class C1
    {
        abstract void f1 ();
        abstract void f2 ();
    };
    abstract class C2 extends C1
    {
        void f1 ()
        {
            System.out.println("f1-C2-original");
        }
    };
    class C3 extends C2
    {
        void f1 ()
        {
            super.f1 ();
            System.out.println ("f1-C3-OVERRIDDEN");

        }

        void f2 (){
            System.out.println ("f2-C3");
        }
        void f3 ()
        {
            System.out.println ("f3-C3-SPECIALLY DEFINED");
        }
    };
    class AbDemo1
    {
        public static void main (String k [])
        {
            C3 o3=new C3 ();
            o3.f1 ();
            o3.f2 ();
            o3.f3 ();
         // C2 o2=new C2 (); invalid
            C2 o2=new C3 ();
            o2.f1 ();
            o2.f2 ();
         // o2.f3 (); invalid
            C1 o1=new C3 (); // or o2
            o1.f1 ();
            o1.f2 ();
         // o1.f3 ();
        }
    };
```

Output:
With respect to Concrete Class:
C3 o3=new C3 ();
o3.f1 (); // f1 - overridden - C3
o3.f2 (); // f2 - C3
o3.f3 (); // f3 - defined in - C3
With respect to Abstract Derived Class:
C2 o2=new C2 (); // invalid
C2 o2=new C3 ();
o2.f1 (); // f1 - overridden - C3
o2.f2 (); // f2 - C3
o2.f3 (); // invalid
With respect to Abstract Base Class:
C1 o1;
o1=o2; // it mean., new C3 ()
o1.f1 (); // f1 - overridden - C3
o1.f2 (); // f2 - C3
o1.f3 (); // invalid